# Update broadcast variable in a RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have this RDD that i've broadcasted.

```
test = sc.parallelize([(1),(2),(3),(4)]).zipWithIndex().map(lambda x: (x[1],x[0]))
return :
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}
```

I have another RDD which is a list of tuple :

```
tuples=sc.parallelize([(0,1),(1,2),(3,2)])
```

My goal is to use the tuple as keys for my broadcast variable and update their values by one

So for the tuple (0,1) my new broadcast variable will be.

```
{0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 4}
```

for the tuple (1,2)

```
{0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 4, 3: 4}
```

for the tuple (3,2)

```
{0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 5}
```

And return the last update broadcasted variable `{0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 5}`

I tried to code it but my results are not good, for each tuples it's increased by one but doesn't take into consideration the last results.

```
def modify_broadcast(j,test):
  main=j[0]
  context=j[1]
  test.value[main]=test.value[main]+1
  test.value[context]=test.value[context]+1
  return test.value

test = sc.parallelize([(1),(2),(3),(4)]).zipWithIndex().map(lambda x: (x[1],x[0]))
test = sc.broadcast(test.collectAsMap())


print(test.value[0])
coocurence = sc.parallelize([(0,1),(1,2),(3,2)]).map(lambda x: modify_broadcast(x,test))
```

Answer (score 2):

When you broadcast, it's something like shared variable. You can use it like a lookup value and treat it as read-only . From my learning, each worker node will have the local copy of that variable and will update it's own copy.That will not be reflected to other worker node as they are passed to every node only once.

From the Learning Spark book:

> A broadcast variable is simply an object of type spark.broadcast.Broadcast[T], which wraps a value of type T. We can access this value by calling value on the Broadcast object in our tasks. The value is sent to each node only once, using an efficient, BitTorrent-like communication mechanism.
>
> The process of using broadcast variables is simple: 1. Create a Broadcast[T] by calling SparkContext.broadcast on an object of type T. Any type works as long as it is also Serializable. 2. Access its value with the value property (or value() method in Java). 3. The variable will be sent to each node only once, and should be treated as read- only (updates will not be propagated to other nodes).

Comment: Thx suresh, do you know another solution to do it ?

Comment: You can try accumulators (AccumulatorParam class ). You can tweak a bit to get it done. You want something like In-place addition. check this,
http://www.opensyssoft.com/2015/07/custom-accumulators-in-spark-using.html

Comment: that link is down . do you have an alternative one pls?

Comment: @CarlosAzevedo [this link](http://opensyssoft.blogspot.com/2015/07/custom-accumulators-in-spark-using.html) was just provided in an answer that was supposed to be a comment and appears to work.